# If scroll inside If is visible

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scroll, unbind

I need to inclose this script

```
var _rys = jQuery.noConflict();
_rys("document").ready(function(){
    _rys(window).on("scroll",function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
        if (_rys(this).scrollTop() > height) {
         _rys('#splash').remove(); 
         window.scrollTo(0, 0); 
          _rys(this).unbind("scroll");    
    } else {
        }
    }); 
});
```

into an if visible condition

```
if( $('#splash').is(':visible') ) {
    // it's visible, do something
}
```

But I am not able to make it work. I only want the scroll script to be run if the splash layer is visible, otherwise it scrolls to top everytime

thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you redefine `$` and immediately use its new value `_rys` (which is just 2 strokes less than `jQuery`) in a `ready` function? In which you then call `$(window)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to the condition

```
var _rys = jQuery.noConflict();

_rys(document).ready(function(){

    _rys(window).on("scroll",function() {
        var height = $(window).height();

        if (_rys(this).scrollTop() > height && $('#splash').is(':visible')) {
            _rys('#splash').remove(); 
             window.scrollTo(0, 0); 
             _rys(this).off("scroll");    
        }

    }); 

});
```